# Flutter Bloc event not triggering

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a bloc (EntriesBloc) that gets initialised when calling run app so that it is accessible to every widget within the app. The bloc is retrieving data from Firestore, and so when generating the initial homepage I add the event (LoadRepository()) to the Bloc which initialises the FireStoreRepo class I built. This event works fine, but within the handler of that Event I try to add another event to the bloc which will retrieve the data from within firestore so that I can display it. The bloc doesn't seem to be triggering this event, even when calling it from other places within the widget tree.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Here is the code:
Initialising the blocs within main:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  final UserRepository userRepository = UserRepository();
  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<EntriesBloc>(
          create: (context) => EntriesBloc(
            userRepository: userRepository,
          )
        )
      ],
      child: App(userRepository: userRepository),
    ),
  );
}
```

Calling the load firestore event within the main router of App:

```dart
class MainRouter extends StatelessWidget {
  MainRouter({Key key, UserRepository userRepository})
      : assert(userRepository != null),
        userRepository = userRepository,
        super(key: key);

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();
  final UserRepository userRepository;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BlocProvider.of<EntriesBloc>(context)..add(LoadRepository());
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return !await navigatorKey.currentState.maybePop();
      },
      child: Navigator(
          key: navigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: generateRoute
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Entries bloc:

```dart
class EntriesBloc extends Bloc<EntriesEvent, EntriesState> {
  EntriesBloc({
    @required UserRepository userRepository,
  })  : assert(userRepository != null),
        _userRepository = userRepository,
        super(null) {
    on<LoadRepository>(_createRepositoryToState);
    on<LoadEntries>(_loadEntriesToState);
    on<LoadedEntries>(_emitEntriesAreLoadedToState);
  }

  final UserRepository _userRepository;
  FirebaseEntriesRepository _entriesRepository;

  EntriesState get initialState => const AwaitingAuthentication();

  FutureOr<void> _createRepositoryToState(
      LoadRepository event, Emitter<EntriesState> emit) async {
    List<String> projectIds = await _userRepository.getUserProject();
    User user = await _userRepository.getUser();
    String userId = user.uid;

    _entriesRepository = new FirebaseEntriesRepository();

    emit(LoadedRepository());
    add(LoadEntries());

  }

  // Automatically streams data from firestore
  FutureOr<void> _loadEntriesToState(
      LoadEntries event, Emitter<EntriesState> emit) async* {
    print("LOADING ENTRIES TO STATE");

    emit(EntriesLoading());

    _entriesRepository.entries().listen((entries) {
      add(LoadedEntries(entries));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `context.read<yourbloc>().add(yourblocevent)`?